# How to align all HTML table data in a table row to be next to each other?

Tags: html, html-table

I am attempting to edit this code to bring the Range 1 and Code 1 texts and input fields to be all side-by-side with each other.

- Setting each `<td>`'s `width` to `20%` or `25%` doesn't do anything.
- Setting the `align` on them doesn't move them.
- I also cannot tell why the range 1/cost 1 row is set to the right.

Setting two fields to be side by side, is OK since aligning the first one right, and the other left, would centralize both. But with four, it separates the entire row by columns, which can't align everything to what I need.

Screenshot of problem:

[image: screenshot of problematic table rendering]

Table html:

```html
<table border="0" width="80%" align="center" colspan="2">
      <div align="right">
      <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><H1>Create New Sliding Scale Fee Ranges</H1></td></tr>
       <tr>
        <td  align="center" CLASS="L1">ContractId:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="ContractId" name="ContractId" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td  align="center" CLASS="L1">Facility:</td>
         <td> <%= prodMgr.getDispenserDDLB(userId, dispenserId, "", "",  "dispenserId") %></td>
    </tr>


    <tr><td colspan="4" align="center">
        <td align="center" CLASS="L1" >1st Range:</td>
            <td>
               <input name="range1" value="" size="10"/>
            </td>


        <td align="center" CLASS="L1">Cost:</td>
        <td>
            <input name="cost1" value="" size="10"/>
        </td>
         </td>
       </tr>
```

Comment: Can you give us the entire table for your example screen shot? It looks like you are using nested tables, but are missing the opening/closing table tags within `<td colspan="4" align="center">`

Comment: do you want four rows with one input on each row, or do you want the third row to have range and cost side by side.

Comment: I need one row, with the four entires all next to eachother and centered properly. The Range 1 text should be in the same column as Facility and ContractId texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Made it a complete table header
- One row
- Styled the heading into a table caption.

**Snippet**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>35490934</title>
</head>

<body>
<table border="0" width="80%" align="center" colspan="2">
   
      <caption style="text-align:left"><H1 style="font-family: Arial; color: orange">Create New Sliding Scale Fee Ranges</H1></caption>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <td  align="center" CLASS="L1">ContractId:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="ContractId" name="ContractId" value=""/></td>

        <td  align="center" CLASS="L1">Facility:</td>
        
         <td> <input/></td>


 <td colspan="4" align="center">
        <td align="center" CLASS="L1" >1st Range:</td>
            <td>
               <input name="range1" value="" size="10"/>
            </td>


        <td align="center" CLASS="L1">Cost:</td>
        <td>
            <input name="cost1" value="" size="10"/>
        </td>
         </td>
       </tr>
       </thead>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below

```
<style>

tr{
display:inline;
float:left;

}


</style>


<H1>Create New Sliding Scale Fee Ranges</H1>
<table border="0" width="80%" align="center" colspan="2">
  <div align="right">
  <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"></td></tr>
   <tr>
    <td  align="center" CLASS="L1">ContractId:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="ContractId" name="ContractId" value=""/>    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td  align="center" CLASS="L1">Facility:</td>
     <td> <!--<%= prodMgr.getDispenserDDLB(userId, dispenserId, "", "",  "dispenserId") %>-->
     <select name="Facility"  />
       <option value="some text">some text</option>         

  </td>
</tr>


<tr><td colspan="4" align="center">
    <td align="center" CLASS="L1" >1st Range:</td>
        <td>
           <input name="range1" value="" size="10"/>
        </td>


    <td align="center" CLASS="L1">Cost:</td>
    <td>
        <input name="cost1" value="" size="10"/>
    </td>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Result
[image]